# Operating system , synchronization

Tags: synchronization

Consider the methods used by processes P1 and P2 for accessing their critical sections whenever needed, as given below. The initial values of shared boolean variables S1 and S2 are randomly assigned.
Method used by P1

```
while (S1 == S2); Critical Section  S1 = S2;
```

Method used by P2

```
while (S1 != S2); Critical Section  S2 = not(S1);
```

Which one of the following statements describes the properties achieved?

- Mutual exclusion but not progress
- Progress but not mutual exclusion
- Neither mutual exclusion nor progress
- Both mutual exclusion and progress

EDIT
why in such codes we cannot preempt during executing `while`? is `while` an atomic expression here?

Comment: Where do you have problems with your homework? Have you tried anything to do it yourself? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

> why in such codes we cannot preempt during executing `while`? is `while` an atomic expression here?

No. `while` is not an atomic operation, and it can be preempted.

For example, while P1 is executing `while (S1 == S2);`, P2 can change the value of `S2`. (Otherwise the program wouldn't be very interesting, since `while (S1 == S2);` would either do nothing or loop forever.)

`while (S1 == S2);` means:

- Read the value of `S1` from shared memory into local memory. (Local memory is memory that none of the other threads access.)
- Read the value of `S2` from shared memory into local memory.
- Compare the local copies of `S1` and `S2`. If they're equal, start again. If they're different, execute the code after the loop.

And `S1 = S2;` means:

- Read the value of `S1` from shared memory into local memory.
- Write the local copy of the value to `S2` in shared memory.

The only thing that's atomic is reading or writing a single variable from/to memory. Other processes can do things, including changing the values of `S1` and `S2`, between each line in the decompositions above.

To determine whether progress is achieved, check whether P1 might get stuck in `while (S1 == S2);` forever, assuming that P2 is running and will pass through its own attempt to reach the critical section. And likewise, check whether P2 might get stuck in `while (S1 != S2);` forever.

> If P1 is stuck in `while (S1 == S2);`, given that P1 is the only one that changes `S1`, it means that `S2` keeps having the same value which is equal to `S1`. But eventually P2 will come along, and since `S1 == S2` it will enter its critical section, set `S2 = not(S1)`, and unblock P1. So P1 can progress.

I leave the progress of P2 as an exercise for the reader.

To determine whether mutual exclusion is achieved, check if there is a way to interleave the execution of the two processes such that P1 and P2 both enter their critical section at the same time. If the processes are never interrupted during their `while` loops, this is obviously true, since either `S1 == S2` or `S1 != S2`. But what might happen if the other process changes `S1` or `S2` at the wrong time?

> Suppose that initially `S1` and `S2` are both true. P1 is stuck until P2 changes `S2`. (`S1` won't change since P1 is the only one that would change it.) If P2 changes `S2`, that's to set it to false, and after that it will be stuck in its own while loop until the value of `S1` or `S2` changes. But the only thing that can change `S1` or `S2` is after one of the processes enters its critical section. So P2 can't enter its critical section again until P1 has entered and finished its critical section.

I leave the generalization to the other initial states as an exercise to the reader.